# How to sort table in asp.net razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

As Title, I would like to sort data table 
I want to sort from current datetime ---> pass datetime 
I'm a new in this programming please help :)
thank you

Here is my code

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SectorID)
        </th>
        .
        .
        .
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateTime)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SectorID)
        </td>
        .
        .
        .
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: @downvoter any down vote should be explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just order the model in a new orderedCollection  here is in your view
or you can do the somehing from your controller

View

```
   @{    
        var modelOrdered = Model.OrderByDescending(m=>m.DateTime);                                                         
     }
```

Controller

```
var model = context.collections.OrderByDescending(m => m.DateTime);
return View(model);
```

//and here just iterate

```
@foreach (var item in modelOrdered) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SectorID)
            </td>
            .
            .
            .
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateTime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: I did what @K.B told me but I sorted by using ID because if i use datetime for sorting, it doesn't work. maybe because of datetime variable is in type of datetime but ID is in type of int so :)

Comment: there is  no reason to not work with datetime can u be more explicit

Comment: I don't really know why but i used ID instead because my ID is auto run number and i my datetime is datetime.now so if i used last ID number means i used current datetime :P

Comment: are  all your records have the same datetime.now

Comment: so it will be evident that you  can't sort on datetime

Comment: Oh i just know that if the parameter have the same value, i will can not sorting.

Answer (score 1):

The view is not the right place for manipulating data. You should do your ordering in your controller method, responsible for this view.

```
//this is where you fetch your data. Just add an .OrderBy or .OrderByDescending
var data = context.SomeEntity.OrderByDescending(ent => ent.DateTime);
return View(data);
```

Comment: he said from current date to pass datetime